# Popper.js how to tooltip slot element?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, popper.js

I have question. How to make possible what Poppers.js tooltip shows around element(popcorn) what is passed thru ?
I am using- Vuejs, Nuxt, typescript for my webpage

otherwise it "sticks" around div element and tooltip showing is wrong .(check images bellow)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="popcorn" aria-describedby="tooltip">
        <slot name="action" :toggle="toggle" :close="close" />
    </div>
    <div ref="tooltip" role="tooltip">
      <div :class="[ci-popover, `ci-popover--background-color-${variant}`,`ci-popover--padding-${padding}`]">
        <slot name="default" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how now it looks like
[image: visual appearance on div]
in inspector
[image: visual appearance in console]

Second solution I tried to add as parameter to slot element ref="popcorn"

```
<slot ref="popcorn" name="action" :toggle="toggle" :close="close" />
```

but it breaks Popper.js and just displays vertically tooltip.

```
Popper: Invalid reference or popper argument provided. They must be either a DOM element or virtual element.
```

[image: error picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Solution was to use "span' instead of 'div' tags.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span ref="popcorn">
      <slot name="action" :toggle="toggle" :close="close">Default Card title</slot>
    </span>
    <div ref="tooltip" role="tooltip">
      <div :class="[ci-popover, `ci-popover--background-color-${variant}`,`ci-popover--padding-${padding}`]">
        <slot name="default" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

result is

[image]